# Reading Contact Part by Part (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I have already read the contact using `CNContact.framework`, as follows

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()
let keys = [CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as! [CNKeyDescriptor]

// The container means
// that the source the contacts from, such as Exchange and iCloud
var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
do {
     allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)

     // Loop the containers
     for container in allContainers {
          let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)
          do {
               let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keys)

               for contact in containerResults {
                     // iterating over contact
               }

               print("Saving into core data completed")

             } catch {
               print("Error fetching results for container")
             }
      }


   } catch {
       print("Error fetching containers")
   }
}
```

In the above code, i have read all the contact at once. Say i have 10000 contacts, and all 10K contact will be loaded into the memory at once. Is there any way so that i could fetch contact by providing `offset` and `limit`.

Say i want to fetch contact from `0-100`, then `101-200` ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question,According to my experience in this field you can not do this but other solutions can be used such as dealing with the display name 
`CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName:"a")` after get ~~a~~ get next  b,c,d........etc then get 0,1,2...9

Comment: i thought that way too, but the possible character set in contact name could be very weird, i have to go through every possible character not only a-z / A-Z, it could be in any language :(

Comment: Yes, of course, it should come in all the language characters,
I think you should make it in the background after you finish showing the user or do as he wants,
Now I've done 70000 contacts and have not had any problems with memory but take a long time

Comment: Have you resolved ؟؟

Comment: not yet bro. :/

Comment: @a.masri I tried this, but not an option as you also have to cover all the new corner cases such as non ascii characters, blank names, etc. In addition the `predicateForContacts(matchingName:"a")` will return all the contact with givenName, familyName and eveni nickname starting with the letter "a"...

Answer (score 1):

Just call [`enumerateContacts(with:usingBlock:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/1402849-enumeratecontacts). It hands you contacts one at a time, so you are free to do what you like with them; and it provides a `stop` parameter to your block so that you can stop receiving contacts at any time.

For example, you could call it the first time, read 100 contacts, and stop. Then you call it the second time, skip thru the first 100 contacts (i.e. just return so you continue with the loop), read the next 100 contacts, and stop. And so on.

Comment: i got your idea, but still confused in the `stop` part. From the documentation i believe `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>` parameter in the block is the `stop` parameter. I'm also confused about how to use this `block` parameter and what it supposed to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue and I started looking at the following function `enumerateContacts(with:usingBlock:)`. As per the documentation, this method is interesting for your use case as it "can be used to fetch all contacts without keeping all of them at once in memory because this is expensive".

When the fetch predicate is matched the block is called and each contact returned one by one if I'm correct but one at a time avoiding memory saturation that can happen when you are dealing with a large contact database on an "old" phone.

Example:

```
var listOfContacts = [CNContact]()
var i = 0
do {
   try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, cursor) in
   listOfContacts.append(contact)
   if i % 100 == 0 {
     cursor.pointee = true // Stop the enumerate
     // do something with the contacts present in listOfContacts
     // first iteration will contain 101 contacts ;-)
     // once done, just set pointee to false to resume the enumeration where you left it
     listOfContacts.removeAll() // clear the array to free some memory
     cursor.pointee = false
   }
   )}
} catch {
   NSLog("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/1402849-enumeratecontacts

Comment: Yup, that's what I already said except you added code, which is excellent.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I think this is more visual as the Apple documentation does not make it that trivial for beginners. Hope that will help other developers